# Can I have a temp column with "Y" or "N" result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Can I have a temp column with "Y" or "N" result?

I have a column name `LastKnownWellDate` which stores dates. I need to have "Y" in a new temp column if date is entered. If date not entered then "N" in temp column.

Example:

```
If LastKnownWellDate is null then "N" in TempColumnLastKnownWell
Else "Y" in TempColumnLastKnownWell
```

`TempColumnLastKnownWell` needs to be a temporary column. It currently does not exist and I don't want it permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [case statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) will do the if-then-else logic in sql.

```
select
  case when LastKnownWellDate is null then 'N' 
       else 'Y' end as TempColumnLastKnownWell
from 
  mytable
```

Comment: Your solution worked as well as the first solution on top. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`Case Statement`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to create the Temp column `TempColumnLastKnownWell`

```
SELECT *,
       TempColumnLastKnownWell = CASE
                                   WHEN LastKnownWellDate IS NULL THEN 'N'
                                   ELSE 'Y'
                                 END
FROM   tablename
```